# ionic - not refreshing ion-content after a call to REST Service (factory)

Tags: angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

I'm new with ionic-framework.
I'm running the application in the browser.
I'm experiencing an issue after I call a factory service. The template is not refreshing its content.
The most weird thing is that when I resize the browser I'm able to see the content (images).

This is my Controller:

```
    angular.module('Tijeras.controllers').controller('PromocionesCtrl', function($scope, categoriaService, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading) {

    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.promocionDetalle = function(id) {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: id
        });
    };

    function getPromociones() {

        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Loading...'
        });

        categoriaService.getCategoriaByID(1)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $scope.items = data;
                $scope.$apply();
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "Error, no se pudo invocar el servicio"
                });
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            });
    };

    function init() {
        getPromociones();
    };

    init();
});
```

My factory

```
var TijerasApp = angular.module('TijerasApp');

TijerasApp.factory('categoriaService', function($http){
    return {
        getCategoriaByID: function(id, callback){
            return $http.get('http://192.168.1.9:8080/CategoriaService/categoria/1');
        }
    }
});
```

The template

```
<ion-view view-title="Promociones">
<ion-pane>
    <ion-slide-box>
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in items">
            <ion-content>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{item.image}}" ng-click="promocionDetalle({{item.id}})">
            </ion-content>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-pane>
```

The result from the REST invocation is the following:

```
[{
    id: 5443544353,
    rootCategory: 3,
    image: "img/promociones/fashion1.jpg",
    text: "shampoos rehidratantes",
    description: "/promociones/fashion1.jpg"
}, {
    id: 2321312,
    rootCategory: 3,
    image: "img/promociones/fashion1.jpg",
    text: "shampoos rehidratantes",
    description: "/promociones/fashion1.jpg"
}]
```

Comment: Could you create a CodePen with this code and just fake the factory to return that data? PS: You don't need to call $scope.$apply();

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had to use

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('content').scrollTop(false);
```

for the updated content to show after a new call to a service where the html template contains scroll delegate handle:

```
<ion-content class="has-header" delegate-handle="content" on-scroll="isMaxScrollPosition()">
```

This moved the view to the top and refreshed the contents. You can checkout the $ionicScrollDelegate at http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/

I'd also checkout the article on [Global Loading Screen with Interceptors](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/loading-screen-with-interceptors/) from Ionic too. That way you don't have to call $ionicLoading.show/hide with each http call.